# Highcharts: Multiple layers of description on y-axis for one data series

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels

I'm looking to add data that has one series and I want to mark the yaxis with both the week number and the month.

Data is something like: {startOfWeek: 'Sep-20-2020', weekNumber: 21, sales: 2500}. The week number is the NOT the week of the year but a week from start of sales (or close enough).

I'm hoping to create a y-axis like the following. Any idea how I might accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: you can do this, but i dont have exact code for it, take a look at  this for [xaxis](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lmtzk1u8) maybe you can figure out,

Comment: Hi @Chris, You can use multiple yAxis with datetime type. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4915/